# Prove that for for every $A \subset R^m$ non-empty subset and $\alpha >0$ number $F=${$x\in R^m:\rho_A(x)\leq\alpha$} set contains $A$ and is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

For set $A \subset R^m (A\neq \emptyset) ,x\in R^m$

$\rho_A(x)=inf_{a\in A}|x-a|$

**Problem.**

Prove that for for every $A \subset R^m$ non-empty subset and $\alpha >0$ number $F=${$x\in R^m:\rho_A(x)\leq\alpha$} set contains $A$ and is closed.

**My work.**

Let $x \in F^\prime$ and we need to show that $x\in F$. Let's say $x \notin F$ and arrive contradiction. So $\rho_A(x)>\alpha.$ Because $x$ is limit point of $F$ for every $B(x,r)$, $\exists y\in B(x,r)$, $\rho_A(y)\leq\alpha.$. I am stuck here, how arrive contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x \in \overline{F}$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then $B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(x) \cap F \neq \emptyset$. Hence there exists $y \in F$ such that $\left\| x - y \right\| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. And since $y \in F$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $\left\| y - a \right\| < \alpha + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. A straightforward application of the triangle inequality then gives  $\rho_A(x) \leq \left\| x - a \right\| \leq \left\| x - y \right\| + \left\| y - a \right\| < \alpha + \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, this implies $\rho_A(x) \leq \alpha$, and hence $x \in F$, which shows that $\overline{F} \subseteq F$.

Comment: Can you please look at this very same problem and tell how to continue?Prove that  $G=${$x\in R^m:\rho_A(x)<\alpha$} set is open.$\forall y\in G$ we need to show that $\exists B_r(y),B_r(y)\subset G$.$x \in B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(y)$, $|x-y|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$,$\rho_A(y)<\alpha.$ $inf|x-a|\leq|x-a|\leq|x-y|+|y-a| $ . I am stuck here because I have only for $\inf|y-a|<\alpha$ @Menander I